# No Method Error but i defined it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, web, rubygems

I got a NoMethodError when i called <%= @post.admin_user.name %>, don't know how to fix it.

Extracted source (around line #4):

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.body %></p>
<small>Post created at <%= @post.created_at.strftime('%b %d. %Y') %></small><br/>   <br/>
<%= @post.admin_user.name %>
<p>Category: <%= link_to @post.category.name, category_path(@post.category.id) %></p>
<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path %> | <%= link_to 'Go Back', posts_path %> |     <%= link_to 'Delete Post', @post, :confirm => "Don't do it man!", :method => :delete %>
</div>
```

Showing c:/Sites/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

---

This is my posts_controller.rb

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
     def index
 @post = Post.all


  end

  def new
 @post = Post.new
 @category = Category.all
  end


  def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
   if @post.save
   redirect_to posts_path, :notice => 'Your post has been posted!'
   else
   render 'new'
   end
  end


  def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id, :admin_user_id, :admin_user, :name)
  end


  def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
     redirect_to post_path, :notice => 'Your post has been updated.'
     else
     render 'new'
    end  
  end

  def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @user = AdminUser.all
  end

  def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy
      redirect_to posts_path, :notice => 'Your post has been deleted.'
   end




   end
```

This is my post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category

 belongs_to :admin_user


end
```

My admin_user.rd

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :posts


end
```

Comment: Its giving you error cuz @post.admin_user is nil. Did you create any admin_user associated with post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@post` you're looking at doesn't have an `admin_user` associated, so `@post.admin_user` is nil.

Either put it in a conditional so you only print out the name if the user is present, or use something like `try` (eg. `@post.admin_user.try(:name)`).